# Why am I getting AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I have a controller with two GET and each need an ID value. One will get all projects for a specific IE. The other will get a single project and doesn't care about IE. When running the app, I get the error Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

```
//GET api/projecttask/ieid
[HttpGet("{ieId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>>> GetProjectTasks(int ieId)
{
    var result = await _projectTaskService.GetProjectTasksAsync(ieId);
    return Ok(result);
}

//GET api/projecttask/projectid
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<ProjectTask>>> GetProjectTask(int id)
{
    var result = await _projectTaskService.GeProjectTaskAsync(id);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>> GetProjectTasksAsync(int ieId)
    {
        var projectTask = await _context.ProjectTasks
            .Include(d => d.DailyStatus)
            .Include(p => p.ProjectStatus)
            .Where(i => i.DsIeId == ieId)
            .OrderBy(f => f.FiNumber)
            .ThenBy(c => c.CaseNumber)
            .ToListAsync();

        return new ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>
        {
            Data = projectTask
        };
    }
    
    
public async Task<ServiceResponse<ProjectTask>> GeProjectTaskAsync(int id)
    {
        var response = new ServiceResponse<ProjectTask>();
        var projectTask = await _context.ProjectTasks
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);

        if (projectTask == null)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "Task does not exist.";
        }
        else
        {
            response.Data = projectTask;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

I tried changing the parameters to named values, but the controller still doesn't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

For once, the message is very precise and descriptive - you have two endpoints with the exact same signature. You are doing multiple things wrong - look at the sample function that is created when you make a new Azure functions project.

Basically you need to use the Route parameter and specify a different value for each endpoint.